# Making a boxplot comparing two variables

Tags: r

I have census data about Salary and Age. There are two possible datapoints under the Salary column (under 50k or over 50k). There are several possible datapoints for the age column. I tried using the following command

```
    boxplot(census$Salary, census$Age)
```

but that didn't return a boxplot that made sense.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Should be used with formula call:

```
boxplot(census$Age ~ census$Salary)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. How did R know to make two boxplots for each salary group. Is it because when I called for census$salary that it recognized there were two different groups and distinguished them appropriately?

Comment: What it was doing was to create a boxplot salary and a boxplot for age if you had given it 3 arguments it would create 3 boxplots.